# Rendering library could'nt be initialized

Tags: android

com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.RenderingException: The rendering library could not be initialized
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibraryLoader.loadImpl(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:89)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:115)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:179)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:171)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$RenderTaskBuilder.lambda$build$1(RenderService.java:562)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I'm getting this error in android studio. Please help me as I'm new here.[The error looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h6tZ.png)

Comment: project cleaning and rebuilding may solve your issue...if not try invalidate caches and restart...if any of this does not work i think you should try reinstalling your android studio